# Power Apps - Change displaymode in new or edit formmode

Tags: form, display-form, powerapps-forms, boolean-field

I have created a simple form in Power Apps, but when the user selects a link to the form for viewing, the form displays no information.

I thought I was writing the correct IF/THEN logic to show or not show the screens. Here's my code I'm adding in the **ITEM** control:

```
If(MyForm1.Mode = New, DisplayMode.Edit, DisplayMode.View)
```

The default form mode is 'Edit'.

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a little confused as to where you are putting this formula. If it is the ITEM component on the form then it will not work because it is expecting a record/item to populate the form fields and not a displaymode value.

The [following link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/controls/control-form-detail) has some good information on the DefaultMode property for Forms but in summary:

If the default mode is "Edit" then it requires a record/item before it shows any of the fields to edit. This sets DisplayMode of the underlying cards as Edit by default.

If the default mode is "New" it will show your fields because the system generates a new record/item for you. This sets DisplayMode of the underlying cards as Edit by default.